# Access navigationItem.title from another class Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

How can I access a title inside the navigation controller from a separate Class? I embedded my `mainVC` into the navigation controller via Storyboard. I can access the title from inside the `viewDidLoad` from inside the same Class like this `self.navigationItem.title = "MyTitle"`. However, I need to access the title from a separate class `'CustomNavigation` like this:

```
class: CustomNavigation: UIViewController() {
   override func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()

      func createCustomNav(){

         self.navigationItem.title = "MyTitle"
      }

   }

}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I also tried this:

```
func createCustomNav(){

   let nav = UINavigationBar()
   let title = UINavigationItem(title: "MyTitle")
   nav.setItems([title], animated: false)
   self.view.addSubview(nav)
}
```

This does't work neither. I don't get any errors.

I instantiate `CustomNavigation` inside the mainVC: `var customNavigation = CustomNavigation()`

Any help would be greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Set up a protocol that describes the work you want done.

```
protocol NavigationTitler {
    func updateTitle(with title: String)
}
```

Define how your class will use the protocol.

```
class CustomNavigation: UINavigationController {
    var titleDelegate: NavigationTitler?
    func work() {
        if let del = titleDelegate {
            del.updateTitle(with: "Title from other object")
        }
    }
}
```

Implement the protocol (this is for your `mainVC`).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NavigationTitler {
    var customNavigation: CustomNavigation?
    func updateTitle(with title: String) {
        self.navigationItem.title = title
    }
    func buildCustomController() {
        customNavigation = CustomNavigation()
        customNavigation!.titleDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the title from a UITabBarItem, use as title in current VC:

```
//Titel einstellen
let x = navigationController?.tabBarItem.title ?? ""
self.title = x //titel in VC
```